# pass function argument to another component reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autobahn

I'm using AutobahnJS I don't know how to use the same connection in another component.

I decided to make it manually by passing the `session` argument to another component like this but that's doesn't work I don't know why

Main component:

```
class App extends Component {


   componentWillMount(){
     this.Call();
    }

  Call = () => {
    var connection = new autobahn.Connection({ url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:9000/', realm: 'realm1' });

    connection.onopen = function Pass (session) {
      console.log(session, 'This I want to use it in anothr component')
    };

    connection.open();
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Two Pass={this.Pass} />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Child Component

```
class Two extends Component {

this.props.Pass(session); // if I console.log session will get error
//How to console log session here

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
       Child component
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Two;
```

What is the best way to use the same connection(session) of Autobahn in another component?

update

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageNumber: 1
    }
    this.sessionVar = this.sessionVar.bind(this)
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
let sessionVar = undefined
class App extends Component {


   componentWillMount(){
     this.Call();
    }
  Call = () => {
    var connection = new autobahn.Connection({ url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:9000/', realm: 'realm1' });

    connection.onopen = function Pass (session) {
      console.log(session, 'This I want to use it in anothr component')
      sessionVar = session
    };

    connection.open();
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Two Pass={this.Pass} session={sessionVar} />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

you can also use state and it will probably be easier that would look like this:

```
  Call = () => {
    var connection = new autobahn.Connection({ url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:9000/', realm: 'realm1' });

    connection.onopen = function Pass (session) {
      console.log(session, 'This I want to use it in anothr component')
      this.setState({session})
    };

    connection.open();
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Two session={this.state.session} />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then you can do this in your child component:

```
class Two extends Component {
componentDidMount(){
console.log(this.props.session)

}

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
       Child component
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Two;
```

Comment: If I put  `let sessionVar` out of Call function I'm getting `Failed to compile` if I put the `let sessionVar`  inside Call function I'm getting `sessionVar is not defined` please help

Comment: How? do you want screenshot?

Comment: I really don't know why This.setState in Pass function not working with no errrors in console.log

Comment: sure a screenshot or just paste the error here, btw it's 'this' with the lower case 'T'

Comment: If I put `let sessionVar` inside call function it's ok, but I'm getting `undefind sessionVar` coming from   `<Two session={sessionVar} />`

Comment: That's better now i'm getting no errors but the  `console.log(this.props.session)` is give me undefined :(

Comment: If I `console.log(sessionVar)` in render of the main component I'm getting undefined

Comment: yes that's because you defined it as undefined and the function probably didn't run yet because sessionVar will only have other value if you run the .connect function

Comment: if i did help please take the time to accept my answer

Comment: Ooh that's right, the only thing confuse me is why i'm getting value of this   `console.log(session, 'This I want to use it in anothr component')`

Comment: because it's still there on your code? maybe i'm understanding it wrong

Comment: Hmmm... actually the Pass function it's running when component mount and we already did `sessionVar  =  session` why I need to re run the function to get the session data in `sessionVar `? that's really confused me

Comment: you shouldn't have to, that's strange... maybe you have to bind call in the constructor, idk what's happening now actually

Comment: I got an error if I bind here `<Two session={sessionVar.bind(this)} />`

Comment: you would have to bind the function call in the constructor ( you would have to create a constructor)

Comment: I'm still getting bind of undefined, check out my code above in my question

Comment: Do you have any idea why this happening? Really thank you for your time