# Error while passing argument to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autobahn

This problem really confused me, when connection is open and I console log session it's working fine I got data but when I try to pass the session out side of the call function and console the sessionVar in render of the component I'm not getting data

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import autobahn from 'autobahn';

let sessionVar = undefined
class App extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
       this.Call();
     }
    Call = () => {
      var connection = new autobahn.Connection({ url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:9000/', realm: 'realm1' });

      connection.onopen = function (session) {
        console.log(session, 'This show data when component mount')
        sessionVar = session
      };

    connection.open();
  }
  render() {
    console.log(sessionVar, 'Im getting undefined')
    return (
      <div>
        <Two session={sessionVar} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You need to understand how react stores states (via the state) and the lifecycle of a component first

Comment: @SterlingArcher Can you please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260017/pass-function-argument-to-another-component-reactjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass function argument to another component reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260017/pass-function-argument-to-another-component-reactjs)

Comment: It is `undefined` because `connection.open();` does asynchronously open a connection and by the time your component renders it is not open yet. Therefore your `onopen` handler wasn't even called when you are logging it in your `render()`function.

Comment: Put the session in your state and call `setState({session})` in your `onopen` handler to update the state as soon as the connection is open. Then your component will re-render with the new state.

Comment: @trixn Yes that's exactly what happening, actually `this.setState({session})` will not work I don't know why with no console errors, I checked the session state in render it doesn't have data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `state` instead. See [docs about React state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

```js
const Two = (props) => <h1>{props.session}</h1>

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      sessionVar: undefined
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.call()
  }
  
  call = () => {
    // Do you fetch session related stuff as normal
    let session = 'session fetched'
    // simulate a delay due to connection
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        sessionVar: session
      }); // setState triggers rerendering
    }, 1000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Two session={this.state.sessionVar} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I'm getting error `this3.setState is not a function`

Comment: I don't want to pass the session via the state

Comment: @Lauradelgado check your `this` definition. You might have unexpectedly losing the correct `this` due to using `function() {}` instead of `() => {}`, probably in some occasions you need to explicitly bind `this`

Comment: Can you please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260017/pass-function-argument-to-another-component-reactjs

Comment: @Lauradelgado well, it that is the case, you better place `session` to a global manageable environment, such as using Redux state. React has something called `context` but is not recommended due to API instability

Comment: @Lauradelgado I am also a bit confused by why the other answer is given that way. But I now believe the reason that you are getting `this.setState is not a function` might be that you did `connection.onopen = function (session) {...}`. This `function` will lose the current environment's `this`. Use `connection.onopen = (session) =>
 {...}` instead. Learn about the arrow functions at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Yes this.setState works fine, but I'm still confusing why sessionVar  doesn't get data even with ES6 function `connection.onopen = (session) => `

Comment: Is there's any other way inside of using state

Comment: @Lauradelgado then probably try Redux (if you prefer to make it globally accessible). Learn about `connect()` that connects redux state to `props` of components

Comment: Really thank your for your time, I got a small problem when I'm getting undefined if I `console.log(this.props.session)` in `componentWillMount `and `DidMount` of the child component

Comment: If I `console.log(this.props.session)` in render of child component it will works

Comment: @Lauradelgado this is related to React Life Cycle hooks and when they are invoked. Check https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-component-life-cycle-823a640b3e8d

Comment: @Lauradelgado Of course you get `undefined` in your child component. Opening the session is asynchronous. When you start to open your connection your code will just continue at this point. It will continue rendering the components. And then at some point when the connection is open it will call your `isopen` callback, which will update your state and only then `sessionVar` will have a value. At this point all your components are probably already mounted and rendered.